# Value height image on mouseover bigger than image height

Tags: c#, image, height, mouse, processing

> ```
>         if (picture != null)
>         {
>             Int32 h = picture.Height;
>             Int32 w = picture.Width;
>             Int32 R = picture.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).R;
>             Int32 G = picture.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).G;
>             Int32 B = picture.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).B;
>             lbPixelValue.Text = "R:"+R+ " G:"+G+ " B:"+B;
>             lbCoordinates.Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
> ```

With the code above, I try to get pixel value from mouse over on the picturebox.

Sometimes this code runs normally, but othertimes, the code error :

`parameter must to be positive and < height`

error at : `Int32 R = picture.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).R;`

I tried to debug, and the problem is `Y > image.height`

What is the problem so I can get `Y > height` of picture

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens when the picturebox is bigger than a image.
Try this:

```
Int32 h = picture.Height;
Int32 w = picture.Width;
if (e.X < w && e.Y < h)
{
    Int32 R = picture.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).R;
    Int32 G = picture.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).G;
    Int32 B = picture.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).B;
    lbPixelValue.Text = "R:" + R + " G:" + G + " B:" + B;
    lbCoordinates.Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
}
else
{
    lbPixelValue.Text = "";
    lbCoordinates.Text = "";
}
```